# Test that a service reacts to a DOM event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I've just wrote this service to alert a user that they is unsaved data when closing the window:

```
    module.factory('autosaver',
        ['$rootScope', '$window', 'editor', 'doc', 'saveInterval', '$timeout',
        function ($rootScope, $window, editor, doc, saveInterval, $timeout) {

        var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
        scope.doc = doc;
        scope.confirmOnLeave = function(e) {
        var msg = "You have unsaved data.";

        // For IE and Firefox
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e) {e.returnValue = msg;}

        // For Chrome and Safari
        return msg;
    };
    scope.$watch('doc.dirty', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue !== oldValue) {
            newValue ? $window.addEventListener('beforeunload', scope.confirmOnLeave) : $window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', scope.confirmOnLeave);
        }
    });

    return scope;
}]);
```

Now I want to write the spec. I can't figure out how to simulate the beforeunload event and spy the call.
I've tried this code:

```
    it('should listen to beforeunload event', inject(function ($window, autosaver) {
        autosaver.confirmOnLeave = jasmine.createSpy('confirmOnLeave');

        var evt = document.createEvent("beforeunloadEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("beforeunload", true, true, $window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

        $window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }));
```

But I get this error:

```
NotSupportedError: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9
    Error: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing direct with the DOM just mock `$window.addEventListener` and call the callback function immediately.

```
jasmine.spyOn($window, 'addEventListener');
```

call you function, then trigger the event:

```
var msg = $window.addEventListener.mostRecentCall. args[1]({}) 
expect(msg).toBeEqual("You have unsaved data.")
```

Comment: Nice way to achieve, thanks. Now I'm struggling because now in my watch function, the new value is always equal to the old one. Only happening when testing, OK in the real app.
I've posted a plnkr to illustrate my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/BezAEM?p=preview